# Filter conversion tracking data by hostname in a custom report using Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

For web sites that run the same application on multiple hostnames, where the hostname applies a given skin and content filter, is it possible to create a custom report in Google Analytics which returns the conversion rate for a given hostname?

I have attempted to create a custom report which delivers monthly KPIs for our business. It is available here:

https://www.google.com/analytics/web/permalink?uid=1_pkuO13RYmVBd8tlRkr6w

The report works perfectly apart from the fact that the 'eCommerce Conversion Rate' remains at 0.00% when I know that the hostname entered has conversion rate data (and in fact can see it by using 'Segments' in standard reporting).

In order to test this, you will need to edit the report and replace the filter hostname with one of your own.

Has anyone had similar experiences where eCommerce data cannot be filtered by hostname in custom reports? If so, are there any workarounds or fixes?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remarkably enough, I contacted Google's support via my AdWords account and got a response the next day!

> Thanks for your email. I understand that you are trying to create a custom reports which displays eCommerce conversions and filters by hostname. As you mentioned that currently this is only possible under the Advanced segments under Standard reporting. Since reports are created differently in Custom reports and Standard reporting and unfortunately at present what you're looking for cannot be achieved through custom reports.
>
> However I have forwarded your feedback to our product specialists and asked them to consider. But I am very sorry that currently due to this product limitation you will be required to see this report under Standard reporting.